# In R ggplot, how to add labels to points in a stat_qq?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```r
df <- data.frame(y = rt(26, df = 5), name = letters)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(sample = y))
p + stat_qq() + stat_qq_line()
```

The above produced the plot as expected.

But now I need labels at each point, so:

```r
df <- data.frame(y = rt(26, df = 5), name = letters)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(sample = y))
p + stat_qq() + stat_qq_line() + geom_text(label = letters)
```

But it complains that `geom_text` needs `x` and `y` `aes`.

how do I fix it?

I found out how to compute the `y`.
But don't know how to compute the `x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ggplot_build()` to get the coordinates of points in your plot. In your case these are found in `data[[1]]`.

The default labels appear right on top of the points. Spacing is adjusted using the variable `offset`... seems to look good.

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(y = rt(26, df = 5), name = letters)

myplot <- ggplot(df, aes(sample = y)) +
    stat_qq() + 
    stat_qq_line()

x.pnts <- ggplot_build(myplot)$data[[1]]$x
y.pnts <- ggplot_build(myplot)$data[[1]]$y
offset <- (max(y.pnts) - min(y.pnts)) / 20

myplot +
    geom_text(label = df$name,
              x = x.pnts,
              y = y.pnts + offset)
```